# Save the textarea value and format

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a problem saving the textarea value and format. The values and the format is not the same when I save it.

Below is my sample coding:

```html
<script>
    function save()
    {
        TestVar = document.getElementById("text2").value;
        mydoc = document.open();
        mydoc.write(TestVar);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id=formtest>
        <textarea name="textarea" id="text2"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="save" onclick="save()">
    </form>
</body>
```

For example, if I am typing the words in the textarea are:

```html
Once there lived a greedy man in a small town. 
He was very rich, and he loved gold and all things fancy.
```

Then, when I've clicked the Save button, the result is shown, it cannot follow my input new line format in the textarea:

```html
Once there lived a greedy man in a small town. He was very rich, and he loved gold and all things fancy.
```

Actually, I want the expected result like the below picture:

```html
Once there lived a greedy man in a small town. 
He was very rich, and he loved gold and all things fancy.
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Typing a new line in an HTML document doesn't put a new line in the rendered document. Nor does copying one from a textarea.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?